# C++ wrapper for sqlite3, alternative to sqlite3pp

Tags: c++, sqlite

Now I use sqlite3pp, but is there a good alternative of it, which can:

- simply return number of rows in query result by call to one function,

At now I must do something like this for simply get rows number in result:

```
bool records_found = false;
int records_count = 0;
{
    sqlite3pp::query select_records_count_query(db,
                                                "SELECT COUNT(rowid) FROM my_table WHERE some_condition = 0");
    for (auto i = select_records_count_query.begin(); i != select_records_count_query.end(); ++i) {
        int records_count = (*i).get<int>(0);
        if (records_count > 0) {
            records_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

- more C++11/14 friendly and more beautiful,

For example, now I cannot do:

```
const uint8_t * blob_data = (*i).get<const uint8_t *>(4)
```

But instead I must

```
const uint8_t * blob_data = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>((*i).get<const void *>(4));
```

And all this `(*i).get<...>(...)` is very unreadable for modern C++.